# How to improve dependency injection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance, dependency-injection, ninject

I have created and IDataProvider interface and implemented it like this:

```
public class DatabaseDataProviderBase : IDataProvider
{
    private readonly IDatabaseConnectionStringProvider _databaseConnectionStringProvider;
    private readonly IParameterApplicator<string> _sqlParameterApplicator;
    private readonly IDatabaseDataProvider _databaseDataProvider;

    public DatabaseDataProviderBase(IDatabaseConnectionStringProvider databaseConnectionStringProvider, IParameterApplicator<string> sqlParameterApplicator, IDatabaseDataProvider databaseDataProvider)
    {
        _databaseConnectionStringProvider = databaseConnectionStringProvider;
        _sqlParameterApplicator = sqlParameterApplicator;
        _databaseDataProvider = databaseDataProvider;
    }

    public DataSet GetData(SqlResource sqlResource, List<Parameter> parameters)
    {
        var connectionString = _databaseConnectionStringProvider.Get(sqlResource.SqlConnection);
        var selectQuery = _sqlParameterApplicator.Apply(parameters, sqlResource.SelectQuery);
        var dataSet = _databaseDataProvider.Get(connectionString, selectQuery);

        return dataSet;
    }
}
```

Now I will need a lot of classes that will inherit from this class. Namely, `NpgsqlDataProvider`, `MsSqlDataProvider`, `OdbcDataprovider` and more. Each of these classes will have their own implementations of `IDatabaseConnectionStringProvider` and `IDatabaseDataProvider`. I will tell which implementation to use by binding them in Ninject module.

Is it a right way to go or maybe there is a better solution? Because before that I have used a lot of factories which created necessary implementations of previously mentioned interfaces and it soon became a nightmare to maintain it. But now, this seems like better approach - I have a base class, from which I will inherit and bind necessary dependencies for inherited classes.

However, inherited classes are just empty - they are using this base class `DatabaseDataProviderBase` implementation and because of that, I feel that I did something wrong. Advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need derived classes just for the sake of completeness. Your base class looks complete already.

The point is in the way in which you are going to consume the class. Are you simply going to use `IDataProvider`?

```
IDataProvider consumer = new ...
```

If so, then the problem may be in newing the data provider. You can use a factory for that purpose and be done with it:

```
void Consumer(Func<IDataProvider> providerFactory)
{
    IDataProvider provider = providerFactory();
    ...
}
```

In this way, you just have to fill the provider factory to all consuming classes and let them use abstract data provider. You don't need any derived classes as long as you are capable of supplying one `Func<IDataProvider>` delegate or the other.

Comment: I would like to inject `IDataProvider` into consumer by using constructor injection. However if I won't have derived classes and won't specify a concrete binding in ninject module, how base class will know which implementation of `IDatabaseConnectionStringProvider`, for example, to use?

Comment: But connection string provider is data provider's constructor argument. Consumer doesn't have to know it. Ninject supports finer-grained setup. You can refer to their documentation for details: https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding